# Customizing a MaintainenceTypeDialog - Not Successful

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Bonjour,

I want to customize the maintaninence type dialogs namely the MaintainenceWelcomeDialog, MaintainenceTypeDialogs ,this is what i did:

I copied the MaintainenceWelcomeDlg from the wix source to my current directory changed the
dialog name to the MymaintenanceWelcomeDlg added a dialog reference in the WixUI_InstallDIr use the light.exe to link the Dialogs to the installer.msi however it still shows the previous dialog, the only change i have made is adding the bitmap to it.

The install UI sequence Looks like:

```
 <InstallUISequence>
<ShowDialog="MyMaintenanceWelcomeDlg"Before="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg"Overridable="yes">Installed AND NOT RESUME AND NOT Preselected AND NOT PATCH</Show>
  </InstallUISequence>
```

Merci.
 And in the WixUI_InstallDir

```
        <Publish Dialog="MyMaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyMaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="MyMaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyVerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="MyMaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyVerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="MyMaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyMaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

        <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="0" />
```

However It still shows the default dialog box when i double click on the installer's icon.

Please Help!!!.

Emma

Comment: Have you tried it without renaming? WiX should find your updated dialog in source and then ignore its own version.

Comment: Does it work at your end , i have the source at the C:\sourcecodewix-b04d4db67458\wix_b04d4db67458\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib , what i did was -removed the MyMaintenanceWelcomeDlg and MyMaintenanceTypeDlg from my current directory where msi is getting created and modified the original MaintenanceWelcomeDlg,MaintenanceTypeDlg in the above said location however nothing happens do i need to add the source path in the environment variables as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't check it now.

Comment: No, I meant you would use/include your own copy of the MaintenanceWelcomeDlg in your .wsx file, but you wouldn't rename your copy but rather leave the name unchanged. WiX does not need its source to compile, thus it does not use it; it uses pre-compiled .wsx files.

Comment: Please see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11306836/572834) below, and try to modify your original source so that it looks as described, and replace MaintenanceWelcomeDlg with MyMaintenanceTypeDlg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this:

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" After="MigrateFeatureStates">NOT Installed</Show>
  <Show Dialog="ResumeDlg" After="WelcomeDlg">Installed AND (RESUME OR Preselected)</Show>
  <Show Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" After="ResumeDlg">Installed AND NOT RESUME AND NOT Preselected</Show>
  <Show Dialog="ProgressDlg" After="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" />
</InstallUISequence>
```

and this is working great in my installer. Try this and see if it works?